# Is there a group reference in grep's Regex?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, group

```
s="/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ncenI12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz: New Century Schoolbook:style=Itali"
```

The best way to extract three parts seperated by ":" is to use `awk`:

```
echo $s | awk -F: '{print $1,"\n",$2,"\n",$3}'
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ncenI12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz 
  New Century Schoolbook 
 style=Itali
```

To achieve same target with `sed` and group reference in Regex:

```
echo $s | sed 's/\([^:]\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)/\1\n\2\n\3/'
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ncenI12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
 New Century Schoolbook
style=Itali
```

Do with grep:

```
echo $s | grep -Po   '[^:]*'
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ncenI12-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
 New Century Schoolbook
style=Itali
```

There is no group reference concept here,how can print the second matched group with `\2`(the second matched group) in grep?
Such bash command can't be the answer without using Regex's group reference in `grep`.

```
echo $s | grep -Po   '[^:]*' | sed -n '2p'
```

Please write a `grep` expression with `\2`--the second matched group to extract `New Century Schoolbook`.

Comment: You cannot do that with grep (GNU) or otherwise, can you use ripgrep, or prcregrep that allows providing such a matching group?